# 10 tps on high throughput chaincode in fabric samples, can i scale it to 100tps ? I saw that fabric can scale upto 100,000 tps

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

OS : Ubuntu 16.04 Hyperledger Fabric v1.3 Ram: 8GB, 4 vCPU

I am using this script (https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.3/high-throughput/scripts/many-updates.sh) to invoke the chaincode 1000 times on one peer.

I am aiming for atleast 100 tps for now

Here are my questions:

1 ) Do you perform multiple transactions on a peer like that script ? Or is there any alternative way ? Can we batch this somehow ?

2) If i were to buy an aws instance, which one do you recommend ?

Went through this white paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.11390.pdf) looked at the possible workarounds for increasing tps but didnt find any good resources to implement these.

Answer (score 0):

[This could help.](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/first-network/configtx.yaml#L226)
Try to set batchTimeout to 1 sec and set more transactions per batch

Answer (score -1):

I saw that we can scale fabric upto 100,000 tps, i am facing a similar kind of issue,
I researched a lot and have the solutions : 
- Parallel Validation
- Cache'ing the endorsement signatures of the endorsers so that we dont have to check again and again
- Have a better configuration
But I didn't find any good links on how to implement this

Comment: 1. Hardware specs matter  
2. Architecture matters too (2 peers 1 org etc...)  
3. Chaincode (possibly the most impact)  
4. Also the configuration of batchsize, timeout etc...  
 should all be taken into consideration.

I have tested myself that it can go up to ~2000TPS.
Currently trying to get ~3.5k TPS